Calculate $\int_0^1 \sqrt{2x-x^2}\ dx$
Consider the following definite integral:
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{2x-x^2}\ dx$$
The first thing I think is to manipulate the integrand to reduce it in a simpler form:
$$2x-x^2=1-(x^2-2x+1)=1-(x-1)^2$$
Therefore, the integral becomes:
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}\ dx$$
I use the following substitution:
$$t=x-1 \Longrightarrow x=t+1 \Longrightarrow dx=dt$$
So, I have that:
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}\ dx=\int_{-1}^{0} \sqrt{1-t^2}\ dt=\Bigl[\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(t)+\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{1-t^2}\Bigl]^{0}_{-1}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
Is this correct? Is there another way to solve it using standard integration methods?

Sounds about right. This is how I'd do it

Another way to calculate the last integral is to realize that
$$
    \int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{1-t^2}dt
$$
is a quarter of the area of the circle with radius $1$, thus the value of this integral must be $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

$y=\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}$ represents the "upper" circle of radius $1$ centered in $(1,0)$, hence you can find immediately the value of the integral:
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{2x-x^2}\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi}{4} $$
